# SQL - choose minimal row

Tags: sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

How can I get these lines (the same lines with minimal operation, and it's not always 2):

[image]

from this?

[image]

And that's my select:

```
select SCR.order_number, SCR.product_code, REL.operation, REL.quantity
from scrDATA as SCR INNER JOIN 
     relBDE as REL ON SCR.order_number = REL.order_number
```

I need to count a pieces for order_number and product_code (e.g. 1500 pcs for `order_number` `FA36001607` and 5 pcs for `order_number` `FP7201127`)

Comment: Yuck: aha, each tables relBDE and scrDATA has their primary ID

Comment: @Yuck - I don't think the rows you mention are identical.  The product_code is different between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
select SCR.order_number, SCR.product_code, REL.operation, SUM(REL.quantity)
FROM scrDATA as SCR
INNER JOIN relBDE as REL ON SCR.order_number = REL.order_number,
( SELECT SCR2.order_number, MIN(REL2.operation) AS operation
                 FROM scrDATA as SCR2
                 INNER JOIN relBDE as REL2 ON SCR2.order_number = REL2.order_number
                 GROUP BY SCR2.order_number) AS SCR_OP 
WHERE SCR.order_number = SCR_OP.order_number 
  AND SCR.operation = SCR_OP.operation
GROUP BY SCR.order_number, SCR.product_code, REL.operation
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this would work:

```
select SCR.order_number, SCR.product_code, MIN(REL.operation), REL.quantity
from scrDATA as SCR INNER JOIN 
     relBDE as REL ON SCR.order_number = REL.order_number
GROUP BY SCR.order_number, SCR.product_code, REL.quantity
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is the query you need:

```
select SCR.order_number, SCR.product_code, REL.operation, REL.quantity
from scrDATA as SCR 
INNER JOIN relBDE as REL ON SCR.order_number = REL.order_number
where REL.operation = 
    (select MIN(REL.operation)
    from scrDATA as SCR 
    INNER JOIN relBDE as REL ON SCR.order_number = REL.order_number)
```